# Python 2.7 Script for moveing X amount of files from/to specific folders

Tags: python

Im trying to make a python script that will move a specific amount of folders(with everything inside) from one folder to another every 'x' days..

So lets say 5 folders (Could be random any 5 folders from within the master-folder folder) moved from 
`c:\User\user\Desktop\master-folder\` 
to 
`d:\folder\destination-folder` every once a week

I know some python so that is why I want to make it in that. I could use any attempt to solve this.

Comment: Hi, can you show us what you have thus far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Yes, I need to figure out a way to move the folders that could have any name that is where i am stuck. Then Im thinking I would use a loop and a time.sleep() to handle the timeing

Comment: And no I can't show you because i don't know how to make the key function of the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here are some pointers to a possible solution...

You can use the following modules to do what you need:

```
from shutil import move
from os import listdir
from os.path import isdir, join
```

`move` will, well... move your folders. Use a combination of `listdir`, `isdir` and `join` to get a list of the folders in your source directory, like so:

```
source = r"c:\User\user\Desktop\master-folder"
destination = r"d:\folder\destination-folder"

folders =  [f for f in listdir(source) if isdir(join(source, f))]
```

then you can use a simple for loop with a counter to move a specific number of folders or whatever tickes your fancy.

Heres an example with a counter that will move the first 3 folders from source to destination:

```
counter = 0 

for i in folders: 
    counter += 1 
    move(source + '\\' + i, destination)
    if counter == 3: 
        break
```

Comment: Very helpful thanks alot will get started right away

Comment: It's perfect mate. Thanks!